# Explicit description of morphisms in derived category

Tags: derived-categories

I'm working with the definition of derived category $D(\mathcal{A})$ of an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ as the category whose objects are chain complexes and morphisms $X\to Y$ are classes of roofs of the form $X\leftarrow X'\to Y$ with $X'\to X$ quasi-isomorphism, under the equivalence relation $(X\leftarrow X_1\to Y)$ $\sim$ $(X\leftarrow X_2\to Y)$ of being "dominated" in the homotopy category by a third roof. That is, there are morphisms $X_0\to X_1$ and $X_0\to X_2$ such that the resulting diagram is commutative in the homotopy category and the composition $X_0\to X_1\to X$ is quasi-isomorphism.

Moreover it's defined (and proved to exists) the composition of $X\leftarrow X_1\to Y$ and $Y\leftarrow X_2\to Z$ as the roof $X\leftarrow X_0\to Z$ given by two morphisms $X_0\to X_1$ (qiso) and $X_0\to X_2$ making the square
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X_0 @>>> X_2@>>> Z\\
@V{qiso}VV @VV{qiso}V\\
X_1 @>>> Y\\
@V{qiso}VV\\
X
\end{CD}
commutes.

Now, my question involves a detail in a proof that I'm reading, where the assertion seems to be that an isomorphism between $X$ and $Y$ in the derived category provides an object $A$ in $\mathcal{A}$ and a pair of morphisms $X\to A\to Y$ with $A\to Y$ quasi-isomorphism. Why is that true? I spelled out based on previous definitions what does being isomorphic means in the derived category, but I can't figure out what should these maps be, especially the one out of $X$.

I guess that something like calculus of fractions is involved (and sadly I know nothing about it so far), but even considering a morphism in the derived category as given by a co-roof, i.e. $X\to Y'\leftarrow Y$ where $Y\to Y'$ is quasi-isomorphism, I can't get the conclusion. Btw if this is the case, could you suggest me any book where to learn about it?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean instead $X \leftarrow A \rightarrow Y$? Because otherwise that's equvalent to saying that if $X,Y$ are isomorphic in the derived category they're quasi-isomorphic in the original category...

Comment: Ok I was wrong, I just wanted to have $X\to A\to Y$ with just $A\to Y$ quasi-isomorphism, I'll edit!

Comment: Er... with only this condition you still can make such a diagram in every case: take $A=Y$, $X \rightarrow A$ to be zero.

Comment: Ok you're definitely right, I'm gonna study more in order at least to understand the question that I wanted to pose, and maybe the answer too

Comment: @Mindlack sorry to bother you, but what about your first comment? Why is that true?

Comment: Not sure what you had in mind... In the first comment, you required a line $X \rightarrow A \rightarrow Y$ of two quasi-isomorphisms, so the composition of which is a quasi-isomorphism.

Comment: Oh, sure, I just meant whether is it true that we can actually have morphisms $X\leftarrow A\to Y$ as you said, which both are quasi-isomorphisms (in the case we assume to have isomorphism $X\to Y$ in the derived category)

Comment: Consider the "pyramid" (commutative up to homotopy) above the sequence of the derived category $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow X \rightarrow Y$ (I'm seeing this as the row which is at the bottom) given by "iso - inverse - iso": let $A_1, A_2, A_1$ (no typo) be the first level, $B_1,B_2$ be the second level, $C$ be the top of the pyramid (draw a picture!). The "bottom right" map $B_1 \rightarrow X$ is homotopic to the "bottom left" map which is a quasi-isomorphism so is a quasi-isomorphism, so the homology map $A_2 \rightarrow X$ has a right inverse. Similarly, $B_2 \rightarrow Y$ (cont'd)

Comment: is a quasi-isomorphism so the homology map $B_2 \rightarrow A_1$ has a left inverse. As this (homology) map is, up to isomorphisms, the homology map of $A_2 \rightarrow X$, it follows that the homology map of $A_2 \rightarrow X$ has a left inverse. Thus this map is an isomorphism and $Y \leftarrow A_2 \rightarrow X$ works.

Comment: thank you so much!